# How do i make that a contextmenu on listBox will take effect on the item i clicked on?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This code is in the form1 constructor:

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
cm.MenuItems.Add("Save Rectangle");
cm.MenuItems.Add("Reset Rectangle");
cm.MenuItems.Add("View Rectangle Information");
listBoxSnap.ContextMenu = cm;
```

Now what it does, is that any item or area I right click on in the ListBox, it will show the menu.  But I want that it will make right click and show the menu only if I make right click on the selected item I'm on now. When I run my program, the first item is selected automatically:

```
if (this.listBoxSnap.Items.Count > 0)
    this.listBoxSnap.SetSelected(0, true);
listBoxSnap.Select();
```

I want that if I clicked the mouse left button to select another item, or moved the keyes up down to select an item, then the menu right click will be available(enabled) for this item only. And if I make right click on any other area in the listBox don't show the menu.

Show the menu only if I put the mouse cursor on the current selected item.

Same as when in windows when I mark text and right click on the it, it will show me a menu, and if I right click on other text that is not marked, it will show me a different menu.

EDIT:

This is working.

In top of form1:

```
ContextMenu cm;
```

In form1 constructor:

```
cm = new ContextMenu();
cm.MenuItems.Add("Save Rectangle");
cm.MenuItems.Add("Reset Rectangle");
cm.MenuItems.Add("View Rectangle Information");
```

And listBox mouse down event:

```
private void listBoxSnap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                var item = listBoxSnap.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
                if (item >= 0)
                {
                    listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex = item;
                    cm.Show(listBoxSnap, e.Location);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem you may add it as a standalone answer and mark it as accepted. It will help future visitors with the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
private void listBoxSnap_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex == -1 || e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        return;
    Rectangle r = listBoxSnap.GetItemRectangle(listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex);
    if (r.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        cm.Show(listBoxSnap, e.Location);
    }
}
```